# Royal Mail PAF or Web Service resellers?

Tags: geolocation

Has anyone used the Royal Mail PAF file to drive geolocation search? Does it include longitude/latitude information? Also, which license type and number of users would a web application use?

Is there any reason to use one of the web service resellers instead?

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 0):

RM = ££
http://www2.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postzon-data

12 monthly complete editions     £2,750

4 quarterly complete editions    £1,250

2 half-yearly complete editions  £750

Have a look at Ordnance Surveys free offering

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html

Might be worth looking at their api as well

same domain as above +oswebsite/web-services/os-openspace/api/index.html